# Application to remote control PS3 Test Kit

Tags: c#, c++, remote-control, playstation3

Any idea how to create c++ or C# application to remote control a PS3 Test Kit on LAN or simulate controller commands to format HDD, create new account etc? A documentation would be splendid.

Comment: If you've ever done development with ps3/psp then you'll know that the documentation is horrible.. your better off directing your question to sony